# Calculating and reporting Data Completeness

Tags: data-quality

I have been working with measuring the data completeness and creating actionable reports for out HRIS system for some time.

Until now i have used Excel, but now that the requirements for reporting has stabilized and the need for quicker response time has increased i want to move the work to another level. At the same time i also wish there to be more detailed options for distinguishing between different units.

As an example I am looking at missing fields. So for each employee in every company I simply want to count how many fields are missing.

For other fields I am looking to validate data - like birthdays compared to hiring dates, threshold for different values, employee groups compared to responsibility level, and so on.

My question is where to move from here. Is there any language that is better than any of the others when dealing with importing lists, doing evaluations on fields in the lists and then quantify it on company and other levels? I want to be able to extract data from our different systems, then have a program do all calculations and summarize the findings in some way. (I consider it to be a good learning experience.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this in the past and sort of cheated.  I wrote a program that ran nightly, identified missing fields (not required but necessary for data integrity) and dumped those to an incomplete record table that was cleared each night before the process ran.  I then sent batch emails to each of the different groups responsible for the missing element(s) to the responsible group (Payroll/Benefits/Compensation/HR Admin) so the missing data could be added.  I used .Net against and Oracle database and sent emails via Lotus Notes, but a similar design should work on just about any environment.